# strftime behavior with time at midnight

Tags: php, strftime

given is follwing date and time: `25. February 2018 00:00` (ISO 8601    2018-02-25T00:00:00+00:00). A conversation to an UNIX-Timestamp is: `1519516800`

Using PHP strftime:

```
echo strftime("%a %d-%m-%Y", 1519516800);
```

gives me

```
Sat 24-02-2018
```

where I would expect

```
Sun 25-02-2018
```

How can I force an interpretation with the new day? (25th in this case).

thanks!

Comment: `strftime` formats the time *in your local timezone*. I guess you're in some timezone west of GMT.

Comment: Try the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) classes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're expecting UTC you need to [configure it](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) somewhere:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo strftime("%a %d-%m-%Y", 1519516800);
```